# VBA Excel Store Range as Array, extract cell values for formula. Offset for other variables

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, range, vba

I'm a bit new at this. How would I take the column and put the cell data of which is an integer and go through all values in that range to put it into a function to output the result into another column in the excel workbook. So my output column will be the entire Comm column using columns G, J and K for inputs into the function `=100000*slotNumber+300*xpos+ypos`

```
  A    B     C      D     E    F       G          H    I       J    K
1 Proc Equip Operat Shift Comm Casette SlotNumber Diam Measure XPos YPos
2
3'
```

So thought if I took the values of each and made a for loop I could take the values and somehow do all this, just not sure how! Please and thank you!

EDIT: I have all columns stored, now I must pass the Array values into the function one by one, for the formula `Z = 100000*slotArr(i)+300xList(i)+yList(i)` or maybe I can just place it in the for loop.

EDIT: Having placed the function in the loop...I am getting an object out of range error...at the line of the function.

```
Sub cmdMeans_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim slotList As Range, slotArr() As Variant, xList As Range, xArr() As Variant
Dim yList As Range, yArr() As Variant, cArr() As Variant

Set slotList = Range("P2", Range("P2").End(xlDown))
slotArr() = slotList.Value

Set xList = slotList.Offset(0, 4)
xArr() = xList.Value

Set yList = slotList.Offset(0, 5)
yArr() = yList.Value

'Only one counter required because of the dependancy on the range slotList
For i = 2 To UBound(slotArr, 1)
    'Dimensioning Array
    ReDim cArr(UBound(slotArr, 1), 1)
    cArr(i, 1) = (100000 * slotArr(i, 1)) + (300 * xList(i, 1)) + yList(i, 1)
    'MsgBox ("Comment Cell Value" & cArr(i, 1))
Next

'Resizing Array
ReDim Preserve cArr(i)
'This is where the new values will be written to the comment column

Dim cRng As Range
Set cRng = Range(Cells(14, 1), Cells(UBound(cArr(i))))
cRng.Value = Application.Transpose(cArr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you format your question more clearly or possibly supply a screenshot? I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I can't submit a photo, but I can via email because the forum won't let me. So the letters above represent the columns. Column C (Slot Number) is the excel column with loads of values and I want an array to store all these values, then also store the values in Column J & K for XPos and YPos. After getting this data I would like to pass it all into a function for a new array output..and then convert the output to a range and place it in the column A for Comm.

Comment: What are those `Barcode` type verticles in your Sheet columns ? :$

Answer (score 2):

I get worried to look at your sample - appolgy but really not ***`decipherable`***... So I stick with your question title and comment:

***`VBA Excel Store Range as Array, extract cell values for formula. Offset for other variables`***.

**How store Range as Array:-**

```
Dim vArray as Variant

vArray = Sheets(1).Range("A2:G50").Value)
```

**How to pass array into a function that takes an array as a parameter and returns an array:-**

```
Function passArray(ByRef vA as Variant) as Variant
   Dim myProcessedArray as Variant
   '----your code goes here

   passArray = myProcessedArray
End Function
```

**Output Single Dimensional array to worksheet Range:-**

```
Sheets(1).Range("E2").Resize(1, _
         UBound(Application.Transpose(singleDArray))) = singleDArray
```

**Output Multi Dimensional array to worksheet Range:-**

```
Sheets(1).Range("E2").Resize(UBound(multiDArray) + 1, _
UBound(Application.Transpose(multiDArray))) = multiDArray
```

Comment: I cannot figure out why you are using Transpose so much. Especially in your first code sample. What purpose does it serve?

Comment: I keep getting subscript out of range here...why if I dimensioned it?                                                              ReDim cArr(1 To i) As Variant cArr(i) = 100000 * slotArr(i) + 300 * xList(i) + yList(i) MsgBox ("Comment Cell Value" & cArr(i, 1))

Comment: @user2027945 Apology I haven't taken a look at your updated code. Why do you want to `ReDim`?

Comment: But doesn't using `Transpose` twice have the same result of not using `Transpose` at all? As far as I could tell, the answer is yes. Additionally, the only purpose I can see for your other `Transpose` would be to have UBound check the 2nd dimension which is more reasonably accomplished by just using `Ubound(singleDArray, 2)`. I think you may be in love with it to the extent that you're finding excuses to use it whether or not it makes sense. `Transpose` is only useful if it's useful. @bonCodigo

Comment: @DanielCook, Thanks much, guess I really overlooked that part! Seriously. Sigh...updated ;)

Comment: I just updated my code again. The function now works. I having difficulty putting the arrays in Range....it should be in column N